# Perl: clean up active threads before exiting

Tags: multithreading, perl

```
sub handle_sigterm {
    my @running = threads->list(threads::running);
    for my $thr (@running) {
        $thr->kill('SIGTERM')->join();
    }
    threads->exit;
} ## end sub handle_sigterm


OUTPUT:
Perl exited with active threads:
        1 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        1 running and detached
```

it looks like handle_sigterm exited without cleaning up the thread?

What can i do clean up the threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`threads->exit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads#EXITING-A-THREAD) doesn't do what you think it does.  It exits the *current* thread, not all threads.  Outside of a thread, it's just like calling `exit`.

```
threads->exit()
    If needed, a thread can be exited at any time by calling
    "threads->exit()".  This will cause the thread to return "undef" in
    a scalar context, or the empty list in a list context.

    When called from the main thread, this behaves the same as exit(0).
```

What you want is to either wait for all threads to complete...

```
$_->join for threads->list;
```

Or to detach all your threads, they will be terminated when the program exits.

```
$_->detach for threads->list;
```

Additionally, you want to use `threads->list` to get a list of all non-joined, non-detached threads, running or not.  `threads->list(threads::running)` will only give you the threads which are still running.  If any thread has completed but not been joined, it will be missed.